# Laravel Deployment to Shared Hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, deployment, shared-hosting

Okay, I have not found a correct solution after searching many sources.

I am having a problem deploying laravel 5 project to a shared hosting.

I have followed every solutions out there but it didn't work.

The Problem I am getting is :
[image]

Where I have put my files :

- I have put my laravel files outside the public_html with a new folder
  called laravel
- I have put public folder contains in domain.com/adminpanel
- I am using default laravel .htaccess
- I have changed .env according to my database but app_path is default as `APP_PATH=http://localhost`

I have used before uploading :

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

I am still not clear how can it is trying to find in the

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: is your controller function name login

Comment: I am using laravel's default auth so the controller is Auth\LoginController.php

Comment: Also tried `php artisan config:cache`? Searched your code for `C:\\xampp`?

Comment: yes I have tried php artisan config:cache and it is still searching for C:\\xampp

Comment: @Ray D'vard did you written your code to return page in controller if yes please show that

Comment: @bipin I am sorry, not understood, what do you want to see exactly ?

Comment: @RayD'vard ,did you written any logic in Auth\LoginController.php if yes please show what your function name which return auth.login page

Comment: @bipin No, I have not added any custom functions in my login controller, it is as default from Laravel Auth. except `protected $redirectTo = '/admin';` I have just set the after login redirection to '/admin' and thats it

Comment: @RayD'vard, 1. check your laravel framework code location:- vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    } is this same  2. make sure your auth folder does not start with capital latter as well as you login.blade.php file, is this all in correct formate

Comment: @bipin Everythings fine, It's working fine in local server !

Comment: @RayD'vard did you moved your resource folder anywhere else location in shared host

Comment: @bipin No, resource folder is in the same directory as it should be, where all laravel files are.

Comment: @RayD'vard what version you are using   run composer update and let me know is it worked or not..